# Trouble getting $.ajax() to work in PhoneGap against a locally hosted server

Tags: android, jquery, ajax, rest, cordova

Currently trying to make an ajax post request to an IIS Express hosted MVC 4 Web API end point from an android VM (Bluestacks) on my machine. Here are the snippets of code that I am trying, and cannot get to work:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://10.0.2.2:28434/api/devices",
        data: {'EncryptedPassword':'1234','UserName':'test','DeviceToken':'d234'}
    }).always(function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {
        alert( textStatus );
    });
```

Whenever I run this request I always get back a textStatus of 'error'. After hours of trying different things, I pushed my End Point to an actual server, and was able to actually get responses back in PhoneGap if I built up an XMLHttpRequest by hand, like so:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open("POST", "http://172.16.100.42/MobileRewards/api/devices", true);
        request.onreadystatechange = function(){//Call a function when the state changes.
            console.log("state = " + request.readyState);
            console.log("status = " + request.status);
            if (request.readyState == 4) {
                if (request.status == 200 || request.status == 0) {
                    console.log("*" + request.responseText + "*");
                }
            }
        }
request.send("{EncryptedPassword:1234,UserName:test,DeviceToken:d234}");
```

Unfortunately, if I try to use $.ajax() against the same end point in the snippet above I still get a status text that says 'error', here is that snippet for reference:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://172.16.100.42/MobileRewards/api/devices",
        data: {'EncryptedPassword':'1234','UserName':'test','DeviceToken':'d234'}
    }).always(function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {
        alert( textStatus );
    });
```

So really, there are a couple of questions here.

1) Why can't I get any ajax calls (post or get) to successfully hit my End Point when it's hosted via IIS Express  on the same machine that the Android VM is running?

2) When my end point is hosted on an actual server, through IIS and served through port 80, why can't I get post requests to be successful when I use jquery's ajax calls? (Even though I can get it to work by manually creating an XMLHttpRequest)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone who ever looks this up, the issue ended up being the port that IIS Express was using on my local machine. When I got things to route through port 80, everything worked okay.

Answer (score 0):

1. Are you sure that BlueStacks uses the same host IP (10.0.2.2) as the emulator? I'm not familiar with it so I'm not sure what the answer to that is.
2. jQuery wants the data to be a string, try:

   ```
   data: JSON.stringify({'EncryptedPassword':'1234','UserName':'test','DeviceToken':'d234'});
   ```

   and for good measure, add

   ```
   contentType: 'application/json',
   ```

   in your ajax settings.

Comment: If I go to a browser in BlueStacks and navigate to http://10.0.2.2 I am able to successfully hit my local IIS Server. I tried changing my request like you suggested, but I still get a status text of 'error'. Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: Does logcat produce any log messages?

Comment: When I use the $.ajax function, no nothing is output into Logcat. Interestingly, if I build up my own XHR and try to go against my local IIS Express instance, the response code I get output into Logcat is a status code of 400. But, when going against the actual server with XHR everything is successful.